# is there any way I can set the type as one of array element in a function parameters?

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, react-typescript

```
// This is what I tried, but did not work

function useAccordion<T extends Readonly<Array<string>>>(keys:T,defaultOpenKey: T[number]){
    // ...
}

useAccordion(["panel1","panel2","panel3"], "panel1") // 2nd argument has to be one of the element from the keys(first argument)

useAccordion(["panel1","panel2","panel3"], "panel7") // It should throw a typescript error
```

note: `as const` type assertion works but can't figure out how to set the type assertion in the function argument.
e.g.

```
const KEYS = [
  "panel1","panel2","panel3"
] as const

const initialOpen:typeof KEYS[number] = "panel1" // correct
const initialOpen:typeof KEYS[number] = "panel8"  // Error
```

The question is how can I do the same thing inside a function args.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can pass your type `KEYS` into the generic of `useAccordion` which will help you to correct types on that function's params.

```
const KEYS = [
  "panel1","panel2","panel3"
] as const

function useAccordion<T extends Readonly<Array<string>>>(keys:T,defaultOpenKey: T[number]){
    // ...
}

useAccordion<typeof KEYS>(["panel1","panel2","panel3"], "panel1") // 2nd argument has to be one of the element from the keys(first argument)
useAccordion<typeof KEYS>(["panel1","panel2","panel3"], "panel7") // It should throw a typescript error
```

Comment: Thanks so much Nick.
I was wondering if there is any other way without the Generics , so that users do not need to pass the type explicitly.

Comment: I think with that generic-type function, the only way we can correct types is we need to explicitly pass types into generics. But I'm thinking about your accordion implementation, enums (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) is more suitable than a generic type @SumitDey

Answer (score 1):

One method to achieve this would be to map the values in the array to a union type of the values in the array.

```
type ValueInArray<T extends unknown[]> = T extends [unknown, ...infer R] ? T[0] | ValueInArray<R> : never;

const a: ValueInArray<["a"]> = "a";
const b: ValueInArray<["a"]> = "b"; // error
const c: ValueInArray<["a", "b", "c"]> = "c";
const d: ValueInArray<["a", "b", "c"]> = "d"; // error
```

Check it out on the [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QJIDsCCAnbcQA8AKlBAB7AToAmAzlEugNboD2A7ugNoC6AfFAC8UEuUo16XRiw7oANFAB0ygJboAZhGxQASjygB+EVwAM+gD6xEKDDjyEdAgFxR0EAG5aA3AFgAUP4AxqzotMBQcC7wyGhYuPgEXABEcEn8QlApSb5+waHhAEZR1rF2Ccmp6cJJBdlQAPT1pLis2EEhYVCBxTG28YQVSQo1Q5mBaQLV4zl5ndQ9NnH2iVnDtcPjVZnUdY3N2K3+QA).